# Why system UIButton don't animate when it is near Navigation controller space (left)

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

Why this happened when you click at the button near left side of the View Controller ?

[image: Gif showing how button on the left is not active]

I suspect it is because of presence of Navigation Controller, but I'm not sure.

Could I make button to animate even though I click at this space ?

Comment: odd. can you show some code? Might be a hitbox issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is because of the `UINavigationController`'s `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` is interfering with the touch events of that button.

Try adding this code in your view controller:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;      
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesEnded = NO;
```

**bluesm's EDIT:**

It looks like

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delaysTouchesBegan = NO;
```

is sufficient to bring the "alpha" animation back to the system's UIButtton of iOS 7.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Accept the answer if you feel I solved it sufficiently for your needs. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created the project that shows solution by @troop231

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9cfjldbmri1ja7j/LackOfAnimationNearNavigationControllerSpace.zip